# How can i use resources when using feature folders in dotnet core

Tags: resources, .net-core

Im using the feature folder structure, and i want to use Localizer in views. This usually works fine with the standard MVC structure, since Localizer searches for the standard folders (Views/Models/Controllers).
Since im using Feature folder this does not work(its not searching the correct folders).

Have anyone made this work?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you taken a look around on Google/Bing for similar issues? Perhaps take a look at the following URL for things which you can provide in your question which can help to diagnose the issue that you're facing: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have tried the normal way to use Localizer as documented in dotnet core docs. That did not work since that uses the normal MVC folder structure, and i dont know how to rewrite the paths that localizer should search. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization

Comment: How have you gone about enabling Feature Folders? I've added them on a few of my open source projects using something like the following (https://github.com/GaProgMan/OnionArch/blob/master/Onion.Web/FeatureLocationExpander.cs), but I've never attempted to use localisation resources with it.

Comment: Yeah, the feature folders itself is working great, but it sadly cannot find the resourcefiles.